# How to see other celestial things using stars for direction?

Tags: star, constellations, orion

I have a simple question. I can see orion constellation clearly in the night sky. I read it somewhere on this website that gemini is on the left-hand side of orion constellation. I was able to spot gemini later that night. I was wondering on how to spot other constellations using orion and gemini constellation.

Comment: Southern or northern hemisphere?

Comment: Any hemisphere. I just want to know other constellations using orion and gemini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a constellation map! That will provide much of the information you need.

Here are however some things you can try to spot:

- On the lower left hand side of Orion, you can spot a very bright star, [Sirius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius), in fact the brightest one in the sky. It is part of the constellation [Canis Major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canis_Major) (great dog).
- A bit further left and up you probably see a star nearly as bright as Sirius. That is [Procyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procyon) in [Canis minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canis_Minor) (lesser dog).
- Up, and a little bit to the right from Orion you can see a very red star. That is [Aldebaran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldebaran) in the constellation of [Taurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taurus_%28constellation%29) (the bull). In the same constellation you can see the [Pleiades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades), a bunch of stars in a cluster.

Taurus with Aldebaran and the Pleiades:

[image: Taurus]